# Do we want hats?

Tags: discussion, hats

A year ago Stack Exchange ran a [Hat promotional event](http://blog.gaming.stackexchange.com/2011/12/holiday-2011-hat-dash-the-hattening/) where you could earn "hats" for your gravatar (profile icon) to wear.

[image]

Stack Exchange is going to do a second run of this promo, but they're going to run it on all sites, *provided the site wants it*. The hats will be more generic and not as ridiculous (no decapitated Wampa hats). Mods give the final go-ahead here, but I figured I'd ask and see; once there's a clear consensus one way or another we'll handle the rest.

Hats would be earned by completing tasks like editing a question, getting upvotes, stuff you do to get badges, but you can show them off while the event is active. These would show up only on the /User page and on question pages, and there's an "I hate hats" button you can use (per-user) to disable hats if you're a hat hater.

So, as a community, do we want the hats promo? Y/N?

Comment: ... so totally fun feature with no drawbacks? What's not to love about this?

Comment: Of course we want hats, who doesn't! Those who decline are just being fun succubi and shouldn't be allowed to have hats anyways ;)

Comment: I figured that would be the reaction, wanted to check :). Also I think there's a fun-succubi option to opt-out.

Comment: @Rarity yup, there's an "i hate hats" buttons in the design spec :)

Comment: Whoever thought of the "top" hat (in the middle) is a genius!

Comment: Hat-ers are gonna hate

Comment: @animuson Ha, actually that's a dreidel hat, for Channukah last year! But that pun never occurred to me -- haha!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

We want hats. You guys were supposed to answer "we want hats" and then upvote it and I accept it. Whatever. We clearly want hats.

### Hats.

[image]

Comment: Of course the fashion designer horse would be the one suggesting more articles of clothing.  Conflict of interest? =P

Answer (score 7):

[image]

## Meh

Comment: Was gonna vote on this, but I couldn't find the Meh arrow.

Comment: @Shog9 Hm, do I smell a feature request? We could really use a Meh vote...

Comment: @YannisRizos `[status-declined]` due to too much apathy.

Comment: @Aarthi Meh....

Comment: @Rarity You are just jealous you don't have a hat.

Comment: I want a "meh" vote too! I would vote maximum every day if there was one, hah.

Comment: lol, I guess I always thought that was like a halo above your head, not a hat.