# Do we want more hats?

Tags: discussion, hats

It's hat time of year again...

Stack Exchange is doing [Winterbash](http://stackexchange.com/promos/12/winter-bash) again. [We joined the fun last year](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/q/525/869), so I was looking to get opinions about this year.

This year, it will run from 16 December 2013 to 3 January 2014. It is essentially, as [enderland said last year](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/525/do-we-want-hats#comment1566_525), a "totally fun feature with no drawbacks" (unless you hate hats, or fun).

Comment: Great, someone else found my comment from last year so I didn't even have to look it up! :)

Comment: I thought we had a no fun policy here :p

Comment: And if you *do* hate hats, or fun, you can say so and the site won't trouble you with having to look at fun hats.

Comment: Flag as "Let's do this"

Comment: Is the goal of "hats" something other than "let's have fun by doing something goofy"? I have to agree with some of the sentiment expressed here that workplace doesn't permit much in the way of fun, so it would seem odd that for a few weeks we would basically say "fun is good", and then change back to "fun is not allowed". But perhaps there's another reason behind this?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere - It's not that we hate fun. It's just that the fun can't be the main goal of a question or an answer; otherwise, it's just noise that prevents us from helping people. Please see [this MSO post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/152483/how-do-the-stack-overflow-community-view-humorhumour-in-questions-answers-com/152507#152507) for a more in-depth answer on how we should approach humor. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, we should have hats! Vote here

(Only upvotes will be counted)

Answer (score 5):

I have always thought the letters look better with hats. I fully agree with this glorious venture.

## a ⇒ â

## c ⇒ ĉ

## d ⇒ ḓ

## e ⇒ ê

## g ⇒ ĝ

## h ⇒ ĥ

## i ⇒ î

## j ⇒ ĵ

## l ⇒ ḽ

## n ⇒ ṋ

## o ⇒ ô

## s ⇒ ŝ

## t ⇒ ṱ

## u ⇒ û

## w ⇒ ŵ

## y ⇒ ŷ

## z ⇒ ẑ

Vive le chapeau!

帽子万歳!

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't think I would want a hat. For many profile icons that are out there, a lot of them are indeed icons from the yore. It would desecrate the icons themselves, IMO. It would bother me to see the profile icon of say Dalai Lama or a happy-buddha wear a hat. Also it would be disturbing to see other icons which are sentimental in nature, wear a hat. Head gear has huge social impact in many parts of the world.

Comment: Participation (including both displaying your own hat and seeing other users' hats) is entirely optional.

Comment: [Pretty sure the Dalai Lama would be all for hats](https://www.google.co.jp/search?q=dalai+lama+hat). Cowboy hats. Lama hats. Patriots baseball caps. The man is clearly all for hats.

Comment: @jmac I just watched 10 questions for D.L. yesterday. What an interesting man he is. Am sure he would also throw hats into the crowd and infect everyone with his smile and humor :)

Comment: Do you realize your icon is the [Fat Monk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Budai) (not a Happy Siddhartha Gautama (commonly known as The Buddha))?

Comment: @GreenMatt Yes sir. Matter of fact, its the laughing buddha. But I just gave it a spin of my own understanding of Buddhist philosophy. Hope you dont mind :) .. oh btw. Siddhartha Gautama, the Buddha, was the preacher of the middle path. It is said he was neither happy nor sad. He was just aware. So there *really* is no happy Gautama Buddha

Comment: @Jim Got it. I thought you were polling for an opinion.

Comment: @happybuddha I am; just wanted to provide some clarification.

Answer (score -4):

No, we don't like hats, or fun! Vote here

(Only upvotes will be counted)

Comment: Do downvotes mean we don't like hats? Or is this a double negative, meaning a downvote means we like hats?

Comment: @jmort253 Updated

Comment: Part of me feels like casting a delete vote for this just to show how much I *do* want hats ;)

Comment: Good thing that Meta doesn't care much about downvoting with rep ;-)

Comment: I am torn I really like hats... but we hate fun here at SE.  So if we get hats no one should be allowed to have fun with them.

Comment: I am confused with this, seeing this answer now downvoted.

Comment: Oh well... Like I said above though, only the upvotes would be counted for determining if a site wants hats